# Joomla hosting with PHP 5.3 +

Tags: joomla, looking-for-hosting, shared-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

Need a good Joomla host with PHP 5.3 + required.  Any good suggestions?

Comment: Any host with PHP 5.3+ is fine...

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat- I'm trying to FIND "Any host with PHP 5.3+"?? Do you know any?

Comment: (1) via Google: http://nephtaliproject.com/php53hosts/index.php or any dedicated hosts (2) Why do you need 5.3 specifically? Joomla runs on 4.3+ (3) I downvoted because it seemed like a bog-standard "what hosting is best" question, which has dozens of equally valid answers. But maybe PHP 5.3 hosting isn't as common as I thought it was...

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat- I do custom module development that's heavy on DateTime functions not available in <= PHP 5.2.  Thanks for the link though, good resource

Comment: Did you find the answer to your question Yarin?

Answer (score 0):

You can use mediatemple. They run php 5.3.x.